# How can 5% and 10% concentrations of benzoyl peroxide, be less effective than the 2.5%?

Tags: dermatology, topical-cream-gel, benzoyl-peroxide, cystic-acne

Herbert P. Goodheart, MD [1971 (Hahnemann Medical College)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/herbert-p-goodheart-md-0a6a7214/). [*Acne For Dummies* (2006)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471746983).  p. 234.

> Benzoyl peroxide is the most commonly used over-the-counter
> acne medication, and is also the most effective medication for
> treating PFB. It comes in varying strengths ranging from 2.5 to 10
> percent. *There’s no proof that anything higher than 2.5 percent
> works any better than the higher concentration*, and the lower concentrations are cheaper and may be less irritating to your skin.
> Clear By Design, Clearasil, Fostex, Neutrogena, and Noxzema are
> just a few of the benzoyl peroxide brand names available.

The statement beneath from [this abstract](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2948929) feels paradoxical.

> The 2.5% benzoyl peroxide formulation was more effective than its vehicle and equivalent to the 5% and 10% concentrations in reducing the number of inflammatory lesions (papules and pustules).

Comment: It's actually not unusual for the most effective dose of a drug to be a lower one.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the outcome incorrectly, the 5% and 10% formulations are not less effective, they are *equally effective*.

The specific text is

> The 2.5% benzoyl peroxide formulation was more effective than its vehicle **and equivalent to the 5% and 10% concentrations**

I don't know how you read that as the higher concentrations are less effective.

The 2.5% formulation was more effective that **its vehicle**, meaning the solution it was added to.

The correct reading is that whatever mechanism benzoyl peroxide works by is essentially saturated at 2.5%, and a higher concentration is simply wasted.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Can you please provide a little more detail on how the outcome of the paper by O H Mills Jr et al. (abstract linked in the question) was misread? I believe I have read it in the same way as the OP, that 2.5% was more effective than its vehicle **and** equivalent to the 5% and 10% concentrations. Not just it's vehicle as that would be a given being as it is not the active ingredient.

Comment: The specific text is:
The 2.5% benzoyl peroxide formulation was more effective than its vehicle **and equivalent to the 5% and 10% concentrations**

I don't know how you read that as the higher concentrations are less effective.

Comment: I now see what you and O H Mills Jr et al. are saying @Turksarama and therefore adjusted my downvote to an upvote. My apologies 

Comment: Rereading the linked page, earlier in the abstract, it does say *"A 2.5% formulation of benzoyl peroxide was compared with its vehicle, and with a 5% and a 10% proprietary benzoyl peroxide gel preparation"* That makes the quoted text in the question more clear